# How to deploy java vertx server on linux?

Tags: java, websocket, vert.x, event-bus

i have made a java server that uses vertx, eventbus, and socket. The client connects to it using javascript. But all of this works locally, How can i deploy this software on a linux server so people online can use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should build a jar file and deploy that on the server. Then start the file with

```
java -jar filename.jar
```

I don't know the context of your application, but it may be necessary to create a web server to let others connect to your application.